# Average of numbers in a .txt file using a scanner

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am currently trying to create a Java program that allows a scanner to read 100 integers from a .txt file and then for the program to output the average of the 100 numbers. It must also check for errors whilst reading from the code. E.G (there is a letter in .txt file, instead of an integer).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
package NumFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumFile { 
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException { 
        try { 
            int counter = 0; // Counter for number of numbers in the txt file 
            double sum = 0; // Sum of all digits in the txt file 
            String line = null; // The line that is read in the txt file 

            Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("Type the name of the file located"); 
            String fileName = userIn.nextLine(); 
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Workbook1.txt)); 

            Object input;
            while(in.hasNextLine() && !((input = in.nextLine()).equals(""))) {
                counter++; 
                sum += Double.parseDouble(line); 
            } 

            double average = sum/counter; 
            System.out.println("The average of the numbers is: " + format(average)); 
            System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is: " + sum); 
            System.out.println("The number of digits is " + counter); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { 
            System.out.println("Input/Output exception"); 
        } 
    } 

    public static String format(double number) { 
        DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
        return d.format(number); 
    } 
}
```

With this code, I am having a few errors. 
Here are the errors that display:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Workbook1 cannot be resolved to a variable
The method hasNextLine() is undefined for the type BufferedReader
The method nextLine() is undefined for the type BufferedReader
at NumFile.NumFile.main(NumFile.java:27)
```

If I remove:

```
Object input;
// Loop until the end of the file 
while(in.hasNextLine() && !((input = in.nextLine()).equals(""))){
```

then the program starts to run, however it cannot find the .txt file containing the integers!

Comment: The initial problem with Workbook1 is that the file name needs to be quoted as a String: `"Workbook1.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
String input = "";
while(in.hasNextLine() && !((input = in.nextLine()).equals(""))) {
    //code here     
}
```

Comment: No.  The question says "... a scanner to read 100 integers from a .txt file ..." - so using a `BufferedReader` to read the file is incorrect.

Comment: If the BufferedReader is incorrect, what would be a suitable replacement for that segment of code?

Comment: @DavidWallace i tried to explain why the errors, anyway i updated the answer.